# Swift: How to check if an AnyObject is nil or not?

Tags: swift, casting

I was trying to check if a variable of type any object (might be string, array or dictionary) is nil or not in swift but couldn't figure out the right way. I googled and used many syntaxes but none of them worked. My application crash when there is no value in that variable.

Can someone please spread some light on this problem?

Best

Comment: Could you show the code where your variable declaration is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a variable/constant of type `AnyObject`, it can't be `nil` by definition (only optional types can be `nil`). What can be `nil` is something of type `AnyObject?` (an optional), and you check just like this:

```
// (optionalVariable is of type AnyObject?)

if let actualVariable = optionalVariable {
    // it is non-nil, and its value is stored in actualVariable
    // (type: AnyObject, non-optional).
    // use it.
}
else{
    // it is nil
}
```

Comment: You need to adapt the sample code below to check for your three variables at once (`gender`, `race`, and `ethnicity`). Unless you are using Swift 2, you are probably stuck with the Pyramid of Doom: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/08/swift-optional-pyramids-of-doom.html